# Why the audio jack(s) sink is not available?

Tags: drivers, multimedia, pipewire

I use [ROG STRIX H370-I GAMING](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-h370-i-gaming-model/spec/) mini-itx motherboard with this spec:

> Back I/O Ports
> ...
> 1 x Optical S/PDIF out
> 5 x Audio jack(s)

I now use only the optical (i.e. 1 x Optical S/PDIF out) as one can see below:

```
pw-link -oI
  39 Midi-Bridge:Midi Through:(capture_0) Midi Through Port-0
  43 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo:monitor_FL
  42 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo:monitor_FR
```

but I intend "to do stuff" with those "5 x Audio jack(s)" too and I assumed to be visible with `pw-link -oI` command but they are not; why "5 x Audio jack(s)" are not listed? what should I do to solve it? should I plugin something in those jack connectors for something about it to be visible with `pw-link`?

PS: I always use the last Ubuntu version (23.10 as of now)

```
inxi --system --audio
System:
  Host: adrhc.go.ro Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/1
    Distro: Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-21-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active

wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.79, gigi@adrhc.go.ro, cookie:312860891]
 └─ Clients:
        31. pipewire                            [0.3.79, gigi@adrhc.go.ro, pid:1958]
        33. WirePlumber                         [0.3.79, gigi@adrhc.go.ro, pid:1954]
        34. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.79, gigi@adrhc.go.ro, pid:1954]
        40. wpctl                               [0.3.79, gigi@adrhc.go.ro, pid:585807]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      44. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   45. Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958) [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo
         1. Audio/Source  alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.iec958-stereo
```